# Append date to text file in MS DOS 6.22

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been looking around and can't seem to find a solution. I'm a total newbie with Windows command line and scripting in general so I figure this is a great place to ask my question.

I'm basically trying to append a time stamp to my script assignments. We submit the batch scripts as text files and I wanted to put append a time stamp to the text document. I asked my professor and he said it was possible but he wasn't sure how to do it. I can't seem to find the solution that I am looking for online. I know how to do this in the windows command line, but not in on the commandline. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

rem This batch file copies all work to a batch file and then to com1:

```
@echo off
cls
cd \
cd menu
copy *.bat mywork.bat
echo This file was created on (this is where I run in to trouble)
type mywork.bat > com1:
cd \
cls
All Files have been copied.
```

Comment: so you want to put there the date when the script itself was created?

Comment: Essentially. When we are done with the assignment we put all of the batch scripts in to one text document, and I wanted to add the time stamp stating when the text document was created.

Comment: Is there more than one `.BAT` file you're trying to send?  What's the purpose of the `copy *.bat mywork.bat` statement?

Comment: What version of dos?  Back in the MSDOS V6.22 days it was common to write a batch script using Qbasic and output the result to a temp batch file to get the date in a variable.

Answer (score 3):

These are all MSDOS methods and will mostly not work in default Windows.

Using Qbasic in a batch script:

```
@echo off
echo open "!_~_!.bat" for output as #1: a$=DATE$>!_~_!.bas
echo ? #1, "SET DAY="+RIGHT$(a$,2)+LEFT$(a$,2)+MID$(a$,4,2)>>!_~_!.bas
echo SYSTEM>>!_~_!.bas
qbasic /run !_~_!.bas
call !_~_!.bat
del !_~_!.bat
del !_~_!.bas
echo %day%
ren filename.xxx %day%.xxx
```

Native way to get the date

```
@echo off
echo exit|"%comspec%" /k prompt set d=$D$_|find /v "exit">"%temp%.\datetmp.bat"
for %%a in (call del) do %%a "%temp%.\datetmp.bat"
echo the date is %d%
```

Using an ASCII binary:

```
@echo off
:: ascii assembler line processing utility by Herbert Kleebauer
:: for the source code and usage information, use this URL
:: http://groups.google.com.au/groups?q=Usage:+edl
::
echo Bj@jzh`0X-`/PPPPPPa(DE(DM(DO(Dh(Ls(Lu(LX(LeZRR]EEEUYRX2Dx=>edl.com
echo 0DxFP,0Xx.t0P,=XtGsB4o@$?PIyU WwX0GwUY Wv;ovBX2Gv0ExGIuht6>>edl.com
echo ?@}I{uNWEF~NPCkaEFAKLCmaIj@KguHaEFCKYCmavh@{HM?cCiuGGwHmYz>>edl.com
echo CgisCGH`LbuuGNO@hRgco{W?dOGg@N?]gBgoG}G?X_SgONks?GN`LBgDu}>>edl.com
echo G?I_DgGNoG?w@jgLiuuroD@?FHoGpBBDcB?1?pIoCRaICSbICn}ExvHmE?>>edl.com
echo coF?DO~yanxCqap?@?lpZrH~sa`LyNHKqDGwQVTNG`CiECICtdL{D?{esL>>edl.com
echo ysICu_{OuD@sCREGHt~F@lgNHYq`EE{S~{Hq_gC{Lr@CE{HQ}@ExuCNQmB>>edl.com
echo BwjFCs?osqs?}n`LKLj?o{}HwJvClpCSEGt~~1}HGGHCSaCU}GiuJaxLCS>>edl.com
echo c}BWuNC_FE{sCkEGFAPqCmEGNAcQNJwLECuQsa{Oe~CK~CkqCmeGmEFbCN>>edl.com
echo C?kEFbBaCGH1jnjBrz?JAcqo~O~?lJgvxs~CspajF{oFEBHijnjBrz?JAc>>edl.com
echo vx~O~?QJLqos~CspFjN{xFEByijnj@ComJcIpCSAijZNUmJaujC{U]JaJB>>edl.com
echo CcClmCJ\jbCS]GFrj~CkEGjBSookVBA_@NJBHmClnEj1JYjxCoIBrh{BFC>>edl.com
echo HtdCWECaBsCC@ZgB@WgB}fj~BsMV@NgB~chvsb{Os{AR{msDUsycsk{SK{>>edl.com
echo VQ{ZsH\sQdsq{Sj{cAICNWl{~B1CNW_K~BxVkSfCA?Cb@N}W@{=sIfjBH}>>edl.com
echo G}N}NK}NNguM@[umCqBJqD@mzDCCClmCJFuhClmC{@jJSN?`CWEG{Cs@Pt>>edl.com
echo cc?AyAFZp{CkEGjBEpEFDNCCkq=jBktx{S[zDgsjCKtl{S]zDgjjCKtc{S>>edl.com
echo _zDgajCKtG{SazDgXjCKtL{SczDgOjCKtR{SezDgFjCKtX{SYzMgFICG?K>>edl.com
echo gF@FIE?EgF}ZhziEuRN~CK}~DqgLoqo?t_ogIKEh?{JU=fCguGiuz_FrCC>>edl.com
echo sCyOjEEsjwr~EvPK~CSqCt~FS}Ha}HCGxCUqERNG]CRQa_BfsCoaoy?h@x>>edl.com
echo CGJH?w``LRaDBBobc?q?a_q?C_0x>>edl.com

:: creates a variable in YYYYMMDD format

echo.!|edl "" "set date=$tY$ty$tm$td">temp.bat
call temp.bat
del temp.bat
echo %date%
del edl.com

:: $tY          : year   - leading  2 digits        (20 for 2003)
:: $ty          : year   - trailing 2 digits        (13 for 2013)
:: $tm          : month  - 2 digits
:: $td          : day    - 2 digits
:: $tH          : hour   - 2 digits in military time (23:00 is 11pm)
:: $tM          : minute - 2 digits
:: $tS          : second - 2 digits
```

Another MSDOS method that gives various date and time info:

```
:: D8TIME.BAT by Larry Nelson from BATPOWER Fidonet Echo
:: Modified 17/07/1995 
 @echo off
::      goto %1
:: Setup Magic.bat with %temp% in it withour CR/LF

       echo %temp%>%temp%b4.bat
       for %%x in (rcx 3 w q) do echo %%x>>%temp%b4.scr
       ::              ^ (2h=2 chars, 3h=3 chars, 4h=4 chars, etc.)
       debug %temp%b4.bat<%temp%b4.scr>nul

 :d8ti
      echo set d8ti=%%3 %%4 >%temp%!.bat
         echo y|copy %temp%b4.bat %temp%magic.bat>nul
         dir %temp%!.bat |find "!" >>%temp%magic.bat
         call %temp%magic.bat
::      goto L8r
 :d8
      echo set d8=%%3 >%temp%!.bat
         echo y|copy %temp%b4.bat %temp%magic.bat>nul
         dir %temp%!.bat |find "!" >>%temp%magic.bat
         call %temp%magic.bat
::      goto L8r
 :time
      echo set time=%%4 >%temp%!.bat
         echo y|copy %temp%b4.bat %temp%magic.bat>nul
         dir %temp%!.bat |find "!" >>%temp%magic.bat
         call %temp%magic.bat
::      goto L8r
 :day
         echo y|copy %temp%b4.bat %temp%magic.bat>nul
         ver |date |find/i "current" >>%temp%magic.bat
         echo set day=%%3 >%temp%current.bat
         call %temp%magic.bat
::     goto L8r
 :L8r
for %%q in (magic current ! b4) do if exist %temp%%%q.bat del %temp%%%q.bat
if exist %temp%b4.scr del %temp%b4.scr
set 
pause
 :: D8TIME.bat
 :: Usage = d8time d8 (date) time (time) d8ti (date/time) day (day of week).
 :: Datetime pulls system date and/or time, or day of the
 :: week and puts it into an envar with current date/time,
 :: date, or time. Find.exe must be in path. A sample usage
 :: of Datetime is Bootlog.bat below. With { call bootlog }
 :: in your Autoexec.bat a file named Bootlog.dat will
 :: receive a record of every time your computer is booted up.
      ::
      ::BOOTLOG.BAT
      :: 
      ::         @echo off
      ::         cls
      ::               call d8time d8ti
      ::            echo %d8ti% >>bootlog.dat
      ::               set d8ti=
      ::         :L8r
```

Comment: wow...1995 . At that time I had not touched a computer yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%DATE%` and/or `%TIME%` variables:

```
> echo %DATE% %TIME%
2014-09-23 13:43:03.02
```

Alternatively, you can use the `DATE` and/or `TIME` *commands*:

```
> date /t
2014-09-23
> time /t
13:56
```

The `/t` switch means "don't prompt to *set* the date/time, just output the current value". You can pipe the output of the commands to a file like this:

```
date /t >> mywork.bat
```

The `>>` means append the output to the end of the file.

Comment: I have tried using %date% but I had no luck with  that. I tried doing the same thing in the windows command line and it worked like I wanted it to, so perhaps these variables are not available in md dos?

Comment: Yeah my professor wanted to start with "the basics" before we move on to Linux and what not. I'm running DOS 6.22 in VMWare Workstation 10.

Comment: OK, I *think* the `date` command will work in DOS 6. See my edit.

Comment: This seems to be crashing my vm. I believe another student tried the same thing earlier and they crashed as well.

Comment: Well.. I'm out of ideas I'm afraid. At this point, I would personally give up and wait until the class got to use an OS that was released less than 20 years ago (lol)

Comment: Dos... If your professor wants to prove that Linux is the better OS, he choosed the right way. Always a matter of what to compare with :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "script=%~f0"
set "script=%script:\=\\%"
:: Define simple macros to support JavaScript within batch
set "beginJS=mshta "javascript:close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write("
set "endJS=));""
set "JS=(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetFile('%script%')).DateCreated"

for /f %%N in (
  '%beginJS% %JS% %endJS%'
) do set date_created=%%N

rem checks if time stamp function is created
call :getTimeStamp >nul 2>&1 || (
    echo(>>"%~f0"
    echo :getTimeStamp >>"%~f0"
    echo echo created on %date_created% >>"%~f0"
    echo goto :eof  >>"%~f0"
)
endlocal

::::::::your code goes here


cls
cd \
cd menu
copy *.bat mywork.bat
::this line is changed
call :getTimeStamp
type mywork.bat > com1:
cd \
cls
All Files have been copied. 

::::::::end of your code

goto :eof
```

**EDIT**

This is about a REAL dos.Just saw the comments bellow.

This will totally not work on DOS - no call :lablel , no MSHTA , no FOR /F ...

Despite I have no willingness to delete my answer - it was not so easy to get the creation date of the file ,and append a new subroutine (only if there is no already) that prints the date.At least was a good exercise .

Comment: Thanks for the post, regardless. I am totally lost. The time stamp isn't required, it was just brought up by a student earlier and I wanted to try and figure out how to do it, but I'm at a bit of a stand still.